# Getting the page title from Chrome Custom Tabs

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I need to receive both the url and the title of the page from a Chrome Custom Tabs action button. Here is how I create it:

```
CustomTabsIntent.Builder intentBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
String actionLabel = getString(R.string.label_action);
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), android.R.drawable.ic_menu_share);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = createPendingIntent(ActionBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_ACTION_BUTTON);
intentBuilder.setActionButton(icon, actionLabel, pendingIntent);
```

And my receiver as follows:

```
public class ActionBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String url = intent.getDataString();
        String title = ?????
```

I cannot find anywhere in the documentation how to get the title of the page. My only current option to make a http request from the app and parse the title tag to find it. Yikes.

Any ideas?